# Keyboardavoidingview only moves last child

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I'm having a really hard time getting KeyboardAvoidingView to work properly.

I want to wrap it around a FlatList of comments and an TextInput to add a new comment. When the keyboard is active, both elements should be moved upwards. If you use Instagram, exactly as their comments screen.

However, whatever I try, it is only the TextInput that gets moved upwards, over the comments.

```
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" keyboardVerticalOffset={65} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <FlatList
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            data={comments}
            keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
            ref={commentList => {
              this.commentList = commentList;
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <CommentItem {...item} />}
          />
          <CommentForm updateId={updateId} userId={userId} />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
```

Any help would be very welcome.

I already tried a combination of Views and adding the TextInput as Footer, which all didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had much better success using `react-native-keyboard-spacer`. Perhaps give that a go?